# Convert a text into a nested list

Tags: python, loops, text, nested-lists

I am trying to split a text into several lists. I have tried several ways, but I had no success.

Here is an example:

```
text_1 = "A-0  100  20  10  A-1  100  12  6  A-2  100  10  5"
```

The result I would like to have is the following:

```
[['A-0', '100', '20', '10'], ['A-1', '100', '12', '6'], ['A-2', '100', '10', '5']]
```

I used regex to identify `A-` as a delimiter for the split. However, I am struggling splitting it. Maybe there is a better way to solve this?

This is just an example, since the solution I am using for a PDF data extractor I managed to built.

Comment: You could just split the text at every whitespace (using `text_1.split()`) and then group each four items in one sublist. What exactly did you try and what was the problem with it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be a bit easier to do with the builtin string method `.split`. With this, you can do the following:

```
# Add whitespace at the end of text_1 so that 
# the final split will be the same format as all other splits

text_1="A-0 100 20 10 A-1 100 12 6 A-2 100 10 5" + " "


step1 = text_1.split("A-")

# [1:] here because we want to ignore the first empty string from split
step2 = ["A-" + i for i in step1[1:]] 

# [:-1] here because we know the last element in the new split will always be empty 
# because of the whitespace before the next "A-"
final = [i.split(' ')[:-1] for i in step2]
```

Final will be:

```
[['A-0', '100', '20', '10'], 
['A-1', '100', '12', '6'], 
['A-2', '100', '10', '5']]
```

This should work for arbitrary sized lists.

Comment: What  happened to the 5 at the end?

Comment: Ah, the [:-1] is removing that because there's no trailing whitespace at the end of the string as there is in each of the other splits.

I suppose you could add in a whitespace before doing the splits, with
`text_1 + " "`
That being said, I'm sure there's a more optimal to get around it while still making it work for arbitrary sized lists.

Comment: Hi, I tried this option, just to make sure if it works with an arbitrary list. It did work ( some more extra job to clean up the data , though). However, Could you clarify me the following : mid = ["A-" + i for i in split[1:]] ( I quite dont understand "i for i in split[1:] and i.split('')[:-1] for i in mid. I get that "each i in split" but why "i for i, and why i.split('')[:-1] for i?

Comment: The `[i for i in iterable]` syntax is called list comprehension. You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Essentially I'm re-creating the list called `split`, and adding back in the "A-" that was removed from `text_1.split()`.

The reason that I use i.split(" ")[:-1] for the final is that for each of the strings in `mid`, there is a trailing whitespace at the end which would create an extra element that is just a blank string in each sub-list in `final`.

Comment: Changed variable names in my example to be less confusing.

`split` is now `step1`
`mid` is now `step2`

Answer (score 2):

If you know you'll always have groups of `4`, can play with `zip` and `iter`

```
x = iter(text_1.split())
```

Then

```
list(zip(*[x]*4)) # or list(zip(x,x,x,x))
```

Yields

```
[('A-0', '100', '20', '10'),
 ('A-1', '100', '12', '6'),
 ('A-2', '100', '10', '5')]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my soloution:

```
text_1 = "A-0  100  20  10  A-1  100  12  6  A-2  100  10  5"
# split text by space
text_array = text_1.split()
# result: ['A-0', '100', '20', '10', 'A-1', '100', '12', '6', 'A-2', '100', '10', '5']

# get array length
text_array_size = len(text_array)
# which is 12 in this case
formatted_text_array = []

# create a loop which runs 3 times and split youre array 4 by 4
for i in range(int(text_array_size/4)):
    formatted_text_array.append(text_array[i*4:i*4+4])

print(formatted_text_array)
# result: [['A-0', '100', '20', '10'], ['A-1', '100', '12', '6'], ['A-2', '100', '10', '5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex(regexes are cool) and have a dynamic number of items in each sub list try this :

```
import re
text_1 = "A-0  100  20  10  A-1  100  12  6  A-2  100  10  5"
my_list = re.findall(r'A-[^A]*', text_1)
for i in range(0, my_list.__len__()):
    my_list[i] = my_list[i].split()
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex based approach –– since you're already using regex for your solution:

### Code

```
from re import split

def split_lst(regex, string):
  return filter(lambda x: x.strip(), split(regex, string))

text_1 = "A-0  100  20  10  A-1  100  12  6  A-2  100  10  5"

print(list(map(
  lambda x: list(split_lst(r"\s", x)), 
  split_lst(r"(A-\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+)", text_1)
)))
```

### result

```
[['A-0', '100', '20', '10'], ['A-1', '100', '12', '6'], ['A-2', '100', '10', '5']]
```

### [Repl.it link](https://repl.it/@sidmishraw/TastyStickyRecursion)